# Home made scatter function, built in function giving ax1 and ax2 if available

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a lot of scatter functions to plot using matplotlib, either on one y axis or two y axis. To ease this, I create my own scatter function: draw_scatter. I indicate in argument on which y axis I want the data to be plotted.

I also indicate fig_param which specifies fig, ax1, ax2 and the function returns a tuple (fig, ax1, ax2) to use the same elements for the next set of data.

I don't like having in argument ax1, ax2 but I don't find how to avoid it. Is there any built function giving ax1 and ax2 if available ? I could call it in my function

I will have then a function to specify the x_label, legend ... of the fig.

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_scatter(fig_param, ax_selec, X, Y, **kwargs):
    """Draw a figure, scatter type, on one or two axis, with selection in argument 
       Input: fig_param(fig,ax1,ax2), ax2 is None if only one axis wanted, 
              simple array X, simple array Y, parameters dict 
       Output: (fig,ax1,ax2), in order to be used again for next elements to be drawn on the same figure""" 

    fig, ax1, ax2 = fig_param

    if kwargs.get('marker_color'):  
        marker_color = kwargs['marker_color']
    else:
        marker_color='k'        
    if kwargs.get('marker_size'): 
        marker_size = kwargs['marker_size']
    else:
        marker_size = 4    

    if ax_selec == 1:
        ax1.scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)     
    else:
       ax2.scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)       
    return (fig, ax1, ax2)  

x = np.arange(0, 10.0, 1)
y1 = 2*x
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # -Set to None if only one y axis is needed 

param = {'marker_color':'blue',
         'marker_size' : 20} 
result_fig = draw_scatter((fig,ax1,ax2), 1, x, y1,**param)

param = {'marker_color':'red'} 
result_fig = draw_scatter(result_fig, 2, x, y2, **param)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively of going global, I think I can use inside my function plt.gcf().axes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_scatter(fig, ax_selec, X, Y, **kwargs):

    axes_list = plt.gcf().axes

    if kwargs.get('marker_color'): 
        marker_color = kwargs['marker_color']
    else:
        marker_color='k'        
    if kwargs.get('marker_size'):  
        marker_size = kwargs['marker_size']
    else:
        marker_size = 4    

    if ax_selec == 1:
        axes_list[0].scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)     
    else:
       axes_list[1].scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)       

x = np.arange(0, 10.0, 1)
y1 = 2*x
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # -Set to None if only one y axis is needed 

param = {'marker_color':'blue',
         'marker_size' : 20} 
draw_scatter(fig, 1, x, y1,**param)

param = {'marker_color':'red'} 
draw_scatter(fig, 2, x, y2, **param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you declare some `ax1` and `ax2` and `fig` as some local variables **inside** the function scope, the changes and updates will be applied to the global variables.

That being said, in your present example, you don't need to pass the `ax1, ax2, fig`  to your function. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) to get more insights into the global variables.

```
def draw_scatter(ax_selec, X, Y, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('marker_color'):  # Il faudrait pouvoir supprimer ou activé tickle sur le x. prevoir un else 
        marker_color = kwargs['marker_color']
    else:
        marker_color='k'        
    if kwargs.get('marker_size'):  # Il faudrait pouvoir supprimer ou activé tickle sur le x. prevoir un else 
        marker_size = kwargs['marker_size']
    else:
        marker_size = 4    

    if ax_selec == 1:
        ax1.scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)     
    else:
        ax2.scatter(X, Y, color=marker_color, s=marker_size)       
    return (fig, ax1, ax2)  

x = np.arange(0, 10.0, 1)
y1 = 2*x
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # -Set to None if only one y axis is needed 

param = {'marker_color':'blue',
         'marker_size' : 20} 
result_fig = draw_scatter( 1, x, y1,**param)

param = {'marker_color':'red'} 
result_fig = draw_scatter(2, x, y2, **param)
```

[image]

Comment: ok, Python will look 'above' if the variable ax1 or ax2 is not found in the local variables of the considered function. In case I deal with several figures at the same time, will I not have a problem ? There will be only one ax1 and ax2

Comment: @Kerdiorp : For one figure, as you have used in your example, my answer would work. If you want to know a general answer, with many `fig` objects, you should include such an example **(complete and runnable)** in your question

Comment: @Kerdiorp : You can also write `global fig, ax1, ax2` as the first line inside your function so that inside the function, the global variables are used. However, for the current example, this is not needed